# Are restaurants open during the Epiphany in Austria?

Tags: austria, public-holidays, innsbruck

Me and my son had plans to visit Innsbruck this weekend but I completely forgot about the Epiphany.

It's a Catholic country, I'm ok with stores being closed, but what about restaurants? Is it like Christmas? Because if it is, than it's safer to give up and just visit Tirol next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, since nobody answered, here's my own update - all restaurants (and a lot of shops actually) are working at Jan'6 just like at any Saturday, so come and enjoy :)